# Writing a data.frame to MySql and getting an error message on rownames when there's none

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, dplyr, rmysql

I'm passing a simple data.frame object to a MySql connection.

The problem is that `dbWriteTable()` call return this error message:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown column 'row_names' in 'field list'
```

I tried:

```
row.names = FALSE
```

as a parameter to my dbWriteTable()

and

```
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

neither of these worked.

Comment: Please provide the actual code that's generating the error, the error alone is not enough for us to help.

Comment: @Mako212 Code added.

Comment: @MehdiZare They mean that you should show the **actual** code you used, including the  `dbWriteTable()` call and the data.frame you wanted to pass. Use `dput` to paste in the data.frame

Comment: Please post a full code block not separate line snippets. I do not see `dbWriteTable` called with data frame object.